# No tests found for given includes when using gradle test

Tags: testing, groovy, gradle

Following is my code:

```
package ro

import org.junit.Test

/**
 * Created by roroco on 3/18/15.
 */
class TryTest extends GroovyTestCase {

    @Test
    def testSmth() {
        assert 1 == 1
    }

}
```

and i run it with 'gradle test --tests ro.TryTest', it raise:

```
ro.TryTest > junit.framework.TestSuite$1.warning FAILED
    junit.framework.AssertionFailedError at TestSuite.java:97

1 test completed, 1 failed
:test FAILED
```

here is [source](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B08GAyjqgToLfndlX2JRZG1ydnpxQzEyM29sQnhjZWp2QVIydzlMS2J2dFZ3a045R1BveWs&usp=sharing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tests need to return `void` for `GroovyTestCase`, so your test class should be:

```
package ro

/**
 * Created by roroco on 3/18/15.
 */
class TryTest extends GroovyTestCase {
    void testSmth() {
        assert 1 == 1
    }
}
```

Also, your build.gradle file doesn't need the `java` AND `groovy` plugins, `groovy` imports `java` by definition, so your file can be:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

As an unrelated aside, I tend to use Spock in place of `GroovyTestCase` these days, so if you add:

```
testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4'
```

to your dependencies, you can then write Spock tests (this would go in `src/test/groovy/ro/TrySpec.groovy`)

```
package ro

class TrySpec extends spock.lang.Specification {
    def 'a simple test'() {
        when: 'I have a number'
            def number = 1

        then: 'It should equal 1'
            number == 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. Also, if you are using JUnit 4+ you no longer need to extend `GroovyTestCase`, the `@Test` annotation is enough to denote a test.